# Which is better and faster to read by devices, barcodes or numbers?

Tags: numbers, barcode, barcode-scanner

[image]

[image]

Which is better and faster to read by devices, barcodes or numbers? Dont care about the storage that barcodes have.

Comment: If you gave this some thought, you might consider the question *Why did they invent barcodes in the first place, if numbers could be read more easily by devices?*  Do you think it's because bar codes look interesting? Because the laser looks cool while it's scanning? Because of the great *beep* sound it makes when it scans?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think the barcodes would be a lot faster and more reliable than OCR. Not sure about 'better' - what metric are you assessing on?

If you're writing an app most platforms will already have a scanner app written that you can plug into.